# Is it possible to permanently block/blacklist a contact?

Tags: delete, spam, billingblock

There's a spam account in my system that I need to delete and permanently prevent from accessing our server. I see CiviCRM has a concept of deleting a contact, but I don't see a way to "block" or "blacklist" a contact. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Blocking would be done through your CMS. For Drupal I use: https://www.drupal.org/project/autoban which allows you to set rules to block IPs and you can manually add IPs.
https://www.drupal.org/project/path2ban Allows you to block user registration/access by domain.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-users/ban-an-ip-address Also allows you to block by manual input of IPs.

I am sure the other CMS options have similar plugins/modules that will allow to keep out the spammers.